# Failed to Load Plugin Vue in eslintrc.js When Building

Tags: vue.js

Dockerfile runs `RUN npm run build` which runs `vue-cli-service build`. After some time, I get an error from `.eslintrc.js`:

Failed to load plugin 'vue' declared in '.eslintrc.js': createRequire is not a function. Build does not get completed because of this issue.

This issue does not occur if I run `npm run build` manually. Why do I get this issue and How can I resolve it?

`.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/essential', '@vue/airbnb', '@vue/prettier'],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'consistent-return': 0,
    'import/extensions': 0,
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0,
    'no-param-reassign': 0,
    'no-alert': 0,
    'no-unused-expressions': 0,
    'no-shadow': 0,
    'no-return-assign': 0
  },
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
};
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "start": "vue-cli-service serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "humps": "^2.0.1",
    "izitoast": "^1.4.0",
    "lamejs": "^1.2.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this fixed by upgrading from Node10 to Node12

Answer (score 2):

Have you run `npm run install` to install all the dependencies before running `npm run build`?

If yes, maybe you need to add some code into your `.eslintrc` file:

`"parser": "vue-eslint-parser",`

Finally, you may also need to add the npm package named 'prettier' to make it works.